# User Record Ownership - October CMS

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

How I set or create that admin user can see only record which he created, or in which he is owner, like in this record this user is selected like owner.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by modifying your query like you can add one field for record which store user id and query can be as followings:

```
$record=DB::table('records')->where('user_id','=',auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

The above query only gives records which belongs to the logged in user.

Comment: and you can give input for user_id field while storing records in the records table write these code in RecordController $record->user_id=auth()->user()->id;